# Does ADFS (SSO) require Kerberos

Tags: kerberos, sso

Could someone confirm if I was to utilise ADFS + Azure connect to provide a SSO experience for Office365 then will Kerberos need to be enabled anywhere in the system (I understand Kerberos is the default AD protocol) ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a SharePoint question per se, but you should not have to do anything explicitly with Kerberos in this particular scenario. Just configure AD FS and federate your O365 tenant.

Comment: Thanks, Just wondering when would I need to enable Kerberos as in screenshot above?